# FeedMe Delete/Disable entries insides

Tags: plugin-feedme

I have a question how FeedMe does behave when I enable the delete/disable entries option.

> **Delete missing elements** - Deletes elements that are not updated by this feed. Be careful when deleting.

What exactly does that mean "not updated"? Does that mean when I run an import the second time with exactly the same data all entries are deleted because none of them were updated?

I tried that case and none of them were deleted. Is the documentation just not exact?

Does FeedMe use also the uniqueID to match when it decides which entries to delete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This option will do the following:

1. Import any new items in your feed
2. Update any items from your feed that it matches to existing items using the Unique ID
3. Deletes any items in your target that do not have a matching Unique ID in your feed

So for example:

Feed contains:

- Title: Item 1 | ID: 100
- Title: Item 2 | ID: 101
- Title: Item 4 - Updated | ID: 103

Your section contains:

- Title: Item 1 | ID: 100
- Title: Item 2 | ID: 101
- Title: Item 3 | ID: 102
- Title: Item 4 | ID: 103

In the above example, using the ID as your Unique ID, your entries for your section will look like this after the import:

- Title: Item 1 | ID: 100
- Title: Item 2 | ID: 101
- Title: Item 4 - Updated | ID: 103

In this import, it matched Items 1, 2 and 4 using the ID, updated Item 4's Title, and deleted Item 3.

The documentation could probably be worded better here, replace "not updated" with "not matched" and it makes more sense:

> Delete missing elements - Deletes elements that are not matched by
> this feed. Be careful when deleting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed specification and verification that it is "only" a wording problem.